# Visual Studio 2008 debug mode hung

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-debugging

For some reasons I can't debug my C# program in Visual Studio!

-> run in debug mode and VS hang (no steps possible, nothing in call stack)

Output messages:

```
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\projects\KeyManagerServer\TestKeyManagerApp\bin\Debug\TestKeyManagerApp.exe', No native symbols in symbol file.
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\verifier.dll'
Page heap: pid 0x1388: page heap enabled with flags 0x3.
AVRF: TestKeyManagerApp.exe: pid 0x1388: flags 0x80643027: application verifier enabled
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vrfcore.dll', Symbols loaded.
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\vfbasics.dll', Symbols loaded.
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\mscoree.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoreei.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\imm32.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msctf.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\winsxs\x86_microsoft.vc80.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.6195_none_d09154e044272b9a\msvcr80.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Culture.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Culture.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v2.0.50727_32\mscorlib\acfc1391e45fedd2a359778ea57d914c\mscorlib.ni.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cryptbase.dll'
'TestKeyManagerApp.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\uxtheme.dll'
```

When I stop the non functional debugger I have to wait approx. 6/7 seconds!

Can someone help me please! (appears only in this project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the project and created a new one and copied the existing files to the new project! After that I'm able to debug! Strange!